# How to access an object's property at array[i] (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

I created an array of type `Account`. Then I populated the array with `Account` objects.
Now I am trying to access the object at `array[i]` so that I can modify one of its variables and move on the next object.

```
public class Account {
    string client;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string planName;
    string startDate;
    string endDate;
    string eeCost;
    string erCost;
    string total;
}

Account[] webData = new Account[3];

for(int i = 0; i < webData.Length; i++) {
    webData[i] = new Account();
}
```

How can I access the object at `webData[i]`?

```
for(int i = 0; i < webData.Length; i++) {
    webData[i].firstName = "Anna";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make firstName as a public variable with getter/setter added, then you will be able to access the properties, By default, if no access modifier is present then CLR treats it as Private

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine in your example. That's exactly how you access a field.

The problem is that these fields are not public - in C#, default access modifier for class members is `private`.

It should be declared as `public` in order to make it accessible outside the class:

```
public class Account {
    public string client;
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string planName;
    public string startDate;
    public string endDate;
    public string eeCost;
    public string erCost;
    public string total;
}
```

By the way, it is better to use properties. Read more about:
- [What is auto-property?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) at MSDN
- [And why you should use it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/226450/should-i-use-automatic-properties) at Programmers.SE

Comment: Just nitpicking, but they are fields, not properties (and they should be properties, not fields).